# Different devise confirmation process for same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise, devise-confirmable

I am using Rails 3.2.15 and Devise 2.2.8. I want to have different email confirmation behaviour for same model depending on certain conditions.

**Case 1:** User signs up on his own using an email and password, gets Mail Template 1 (the mail only asks for email confirmation, he has already set the password)

**Case 2:** A new user is added in model explicitly by another registered user. The new user gets Mail Template 2, which asks him to reset the password (reset should by default confirm his account as well)

Is this possible to achieve?

I was going through Devise [page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Override-confirmations-so-users-can-pick-their-own-passwords-as-part-of-confirmation-activation) where we can override confirmation process to let user set the password and auto-confirm the account during this process. But I think this will happen for all users added in model. I want to customize this.

Comment: Any reply on this will help!

Answer (score 0):

You probably found your answer; but for future ref, if the answer is needed, I just wanted to say that YES, this is possible...

As usual with Rails, you can override anything so this is also true for the confirmation process in Devise.
I'm working on a project where we have different ways of accepting/confirming new users.

If you/somebody needs details, feel free to ask...

Cheers